# How to update label text from functions class to Form1 vb.net

Tags: regex, vb.net, nullreferenceexception

I'm trying to rewrite my code from `Form1` and I'm learning how to implement codes in different `classes` like `Functions`,`Properties` etc...

Now I have created a `Sub` which gets me a YouTube Title of my video , I know I can use API btw but since I'm testing a lot my API limit will be immediately off.

The problem is that even through I declared in Functions `Public Shared Property Frm As New Form1` or I setup a `invoke sub` for label I'm still getting error:

> System.NullReferenceException: 'Object reference not set to an
> instance of an object.'

Here is my code in `RegularExpressions.vb`:

```
Imports System.Text.RegularExpressions
Imports Leaf.xNet

Public Class RegularExpressions
    Public Shared Property Frm As New Form1
    Friend Shared Mainform As Form1
    Public Shared Property txtTitle As Label


    Public Shared Sub getValues_Offline_Title()

        Using req As New HttpRequest()
            Dim Offline_Title As String
            Dim url As String
            Dim _videoID As String = Functions.VideoURL_link.ToString

            req.AddHeader("Host", "www.youtube.com")
            req.AddHeader("User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/109.0.0.0 Safari/537.36")
            req.AddHeader("Accept", "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/avif,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8")
            req.AddHeader("Accept-Language", "en-US,en;q=0.9,cs;q=0.8,de;q=0.7,fr;q=0.6,hu;q=0.5")
            req.AddHeader("Accept-Encoding", "gzip, deflate")
            req.AddHeader("Referrer", $"https://www.youtube.com/watch?v={_videoID}")

            Dim strData As String = req.[Get](String.Concat("https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=", _videoID), Nothing).ToString()
            Dim url2 = strData.ToString
            url = strData.ToString().Split({"twoColumnWatchNextResults"":"}, StringSplitOptions.None)(1).Split("]"c)(0)
            Offline_Title = url.Split(New String() {"text"":"""}, StringSplitOptions.None)(1).Split(""""c)(0)
            'MessageBox.Show(Offline_Title)
            Frm.Invoke(Sub() txtTitle.Text = Offline_Title.ToString)
            'Mainform.lbl_Views_sent.Text = Offline_Title.ToString
        End Using
    End Sub

End Class
```

This method is called when Form1 Loads and there I have 2 radiobuttons.
If Radiobutton1 is checked then it should shows offline video title, else radiobutton2 is checked then live video title.

```
    Private Sub RadioButton1_CheckedChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles RadioButton1.CheckedChanged
    If RadioButton1.Checked Then
         RegularExpressions.getValues_Offline_Title()
    Else
         RegularExpressions.getValues_Live_Title()
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: This question is probably more about how you are calling the above method rather than the method it self.  From a quick browse I would suggest you are better off returning the Offline_Title as a string to the calling form rather than trying to mess wit invoking.

Comment: @Hursey this method I called when Form1 Loads and under radiobutton1_CheckedChanged if radiobutton2 then it should load live video title so it is under

Comment: You should not be moving code out of a form that relates specifically to that form. If you have code that does work that is not related to the UI, e.g. processing data from a database or a file, then that code can go into its own class. If the UI needs to be updated with the result of that processing though, that's the form's job. The other class can make the result available via a property or a method return value and the form then gets the result and updates its own `Label`. That class shouldn't even have to know that the form exists.

Comment: @jmcilhinney thanks I know what you mean so I did it what you said instead of Sub I made function and return string and call txtTitle from Form1 and it does the job well, how ever now I have the same issue hehe with Listview to update the items I will post another question since I did already public shared property for listview but it doesnt update it in Form1 I know my code is a mess thats why I choose to update all codes and in meantime I learn a lot

Answer (score 0):

You must create a form class based on form1 called Frm and assign existing instance of the Form1 class to it.
(thanks to comment if that explanation is imperfect)

this works :

```
Public Class RegularExpressions
            Public Shared Sub getValues_Offline_Title()
                Dim Frm As Form1 = Form1 'create and assign
                Using req As New HttpRequest()
                    Dim Offline_Title As String
                    Dim url As String
                    Dim _videoID As String = Functions.VideoURL_link.ToString
                    
                    req.AddHeader("Host", "www.youtube.com")
                    req.AddHeader("User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/109.0.0.0 Safari/537.36")
                    req.AddHeader("Accept", "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/avif,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8")
                    req.AddHeader("Accept-Language", "en-US,en;q=0.9,cs;q=0.8,de;q=0.7,fr;q=0.6,hu;q=0.5")
                    req.AddHeader("Accept-Encoding", "gzip, deflate")
                    req.AddHeader("Referrer", $"https://www.youtube.com/watch?v={_videoID}")
        
                    Dim strData As String = req.[Get](String.Concat("https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=", _videoID), Nothing).ToString()
                    Dim url2 = strData.ToString
                    url = strData.ToString().Split({"twoColumnWatchNextResults"":"}, StringSplitOptions.None)(1).Split("]"c)(0)
                    Offline_Title = url.Split(New String() {"text"":"""}, StringSplitOptions.None)(1).Split(""""c)(0)
                    'MessageBox.Show(Offline_Title)
                    Frm.txtTitle.Text = Offline_Title.ToString
                    'Mainform.lbl_Views_sent.Text = Offline_Title.ToString
                End Using
            End Sub
        
        End Class
```

Comment: thanks for help but for me it doesnt work calling Form1.txtTitle thats why I tried invoke but in the end I have made function instead of Sub and call the txtTitle from Form1 to function string return

Comment: Your solution is even better: I may have been too focused on the Form declaration ...

Answer (score 0):

Because my code is a big mess I choose to rewrite it and I know I will be struggle a lot but in the meantime I like to improve my skilss and learn better coding.
So the solution was to forget about the `Sub` in the `class` and make a `Function` which `Return` a desired title `string` from the Regex and from `Form1` I only have to call `txtTitle.Text = MyFunction.Function.ToString`